# position ticks in par with data - highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a 'datetime' chart which has one point per day. So my requirement is to have each date displayed on x-axis and value plotted for each date. So I have set the tickinterval as 1 day (24*3600*1000) as follows:

http://jsfiddle.net/vuf5e/1/

However, the x-axis seems to show only Aug28th and chart has two points on either side of it instead of showing one point for Aug27th and another one for Aug28th.

I tried using tickPositions and the chart appears as follows:

http://jsfiddle.net/vuf5e/2/

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

One of the numbers is wrong. 
the second position in the tick is 137766608975 but then in the data is 1377666808975 which has a full digit more than the other.

You are in fact missing an 8 somewhere in the middle.

so basically the number on the second tick become smaller than the first one.

```
    [...]
        xAxis: {
            type:'datetime' , tickPositions:[1377601929269, **137766608975**]
        },


        series:[{"yAxis":0,"name":"Device_INTERFACE_in_octets--.2","data":[[1377601929269,5.8583],[**1377666808975**,6.6278]]}]
    });
});
```